# Suppress "loading" output in Quicklisp

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp

Is there a way to have quicklisp load a library without sending:

```
To load "drakma":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    drakma
; Loading "drakma"
```

To standard out? I've tried adding `:verbose nil` and `:explain nil` to the arguments of `ql:quickload` (which is how I'm loading the libraries now) but it seems that those are the defaults -- turning them on just increases the amount of output.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `:silent` option for quicklisp is missing from this list of answers.  Since the latest answer is from 2013, maybe that option was added after then.

Here's how you use it:

```
(ql:quickload "my-code" :silent t)
```

Answer (score 12):

For anyone who's having a similar problem, I've found a solution:

```
(with-open-file (*standard-output* "/dev/null" :direction :output
                                   :if-exists :supersede)
                (ql:quickload "my-package"))
```

Not sure if it will work on all interpreters, but it works well with CLisp.

Comment: The normal way to make a null-output stream is (make-broadcast-stream). This has the advantage of working on systems that lack /dev/null (e.g. windows).

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a way to do that, but I intend to add a way sometime soon.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using sbcl to run things as a script, you can find some additional help by adding --noinform to the shebang as such:

```
!#/bin/sbcl --noinform --core /path/to/relevant/sbcl.core --script
```